# Can I preserve generics in conditional types?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, higher-kinded-types, conditional-types

Let's say I have a conditional type that changes the return type of a function:

```js
type ChangeReturnType<F, R> =
    F extends (this: unknown, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (...args: A) => R :
    F extends (this: infer T, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (this: T, ...args: A) => R :
    F;
```

This [works well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHYHMICULAK4CckAq4EAPAGIA0U6AfFALwCwAUFG1GVBAB7ARIATAM5QAFMDgBLIQC4o2JAGskAewDuSKgDodCXCllRJSAGYRcUAIIBKBnWQgoAfhbs3YnVr0G5Nu9SgZV3ZOHj5BEXEpQ2MzCwJtXX0Y03MrW3p7JEcXVnc2KOk5BKhPb0M-TICgvLYyAG4WFhMFAGNgSRUkKBMVFVEEOSRsAFsAI3MqMbkhYFxjFGs5ADcVSQEoAG8AXxZQSA4+hih9iBUTHr7G5gB6G8OVOQGh0YncKZm5hYy6VfXrvbEKAAIT0x3gyDQmBw+CIkHIfSoCgEEBMxggAho1zuIL0T0GUGG40mUGmUFm81QP3kglR6IEAOYrQANgghCIAMoqEYQGCs9k7JrMYx8XAmBCtaAASTIR02wTYPIkKgEAEZnoTXiSyRTvis1gyFVAlXAVQAmQqGLk8vlsoRUAlEt5LKB-Q3MXbMQEHACyWFNavBiFQGCweEIxBIMr6AG0AEQmlWquMAXSRtLRSAxWO90D9yoEZqDkNDMIj8OjKnjicLqfTKMz2ex93zAdV+JexPepM+lMW-mRdKz7pxrfNTwkRSg1t5-PtUEdWtw1MHjfdQA) for any non-generic function or method.

```js
function foo(a: number, b: string): void {}
type Foo = typeof foo;
// Foo: (a: number, b: string) => void;

type Bar = ChangeReturnType<typeof foo, undefined>;
// Bar: (a: number, b: string) => undefined;

interface IFoo {
    method1(a: number, b: string): void;
    method2(this: SomeClass, a: number): void;
}

type Method1 = ChangeReturnType<IFoo["method1"], undefined>;
type Method2 = ChangeReturnType<IFoo["method2"], undefined>;
// Method1: (a: number, b: string) => undefined;
// Method2: (this: SomeClass, a: number) => undefined;
```

<sub>I know these contrived examples seem pretty useless, because they're just short examples intended to illustrate the concept.  For a more meaningful, if still contrived, example, see [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-BNgdEPerOdwQkTqvdnu9HfpGfZ-0bbGbFlbRuAUCEIAAth0VB9+za7WHYSWkGXkSAAMoHo8fIPj7O1meOucQL1QcZ7w-Ht2WY1rmf6PseUAICIDirKugLAqCSDgpCPomJIXzmE0NCiJIfC4AgHQfBAcgAJJ4QRRFYVQYCvAIki9CSxF6t0cgEGkdBHseEDIHiUCEkgxI8lhTyOhuYhtjuuEQPup5SfhhEQLYApquwuqiDREB0QxfA4Xw+4fipKket+3pSfuAKBEC8HMCwiHIdC+4IGATRUAAqthckUUxZHEgpVG7t+OJknI8aYis7FQK5vH8YJZIkO5ImBGJW5ppJemyeRCkOoZUDGT+QiBeauC6dJDbWbZYIoihvQNEgTQtKE7TngMoWsbxpx1eciXsM6+BnqGwAGq8jGiMMrzvF8hh-DcVCDoNJgIvuACiSAjmijlgKIs7sAA9DtUAAOrQAIkIAOQ7gJmmQZkUASaaRVCFo23ruheGiBGVLMqO9ZUKIi4gKsEWdtKVpyndZo8sqFDPWI-1Ab2EXKTlu37QAMtxABu0AIL0vRvEIuaQR8kIQE9n6GWp45FjuMpDAomZoQJ3oAD7M8uVZaAVNNWvTECM5p2XIypvWzHD7O9HBMOBHtUDowgWNQGhJnQcTAlk0LQoitG4pUxjCAfNg0C01Acp2VVSDKlAUuGSLv6dvDEvJhr6pYC6dtLkjztsG447Q+TQsyzAw18JBUACWoUD7lgcAqN6EgkruPJvFAEjQONnw7uKqcSpyKDGPr13eiLIjZzVCDGBKzXq17bB6wbTFmxCSA5JE9Tl51NDxO4iRyA4SnW0LESPenk1aGA2BCHAY7slodeG+4YBgB8IChVQRSJhZNdOq7fVD5vNdWc7NxwTlh-sImZVWSwEkpyoABy2CHikQwPgBHyiHKpIP0-uDKsmvQfCgiIGA+teifBJBaT2v4v6Pw6OYVYog6690yEpF2mooAAGo66XCgGfNgCABACFEAgOQSBYHmCoB0Uh5DcCoNtggTBUAOg4LwbubAHQTQ42AMQ6hP9KG8LgbQkYaC3YMIALRMJYaqfcGcuTLx4WHGh-DFE-zoTvWYDCoSSNwaqOiGNJCZgUWQvhTCBHmDUeghh+1mE6PKswG+DEPhgMATyBgt1aqiHDrAUB4CeSiA3sCNsXEtDExQFtFMPiXFklVO4QhogACMVAABMgtvbvA4fhfoCTkmpIKDIr4ciV6JKgCkmJeiDEQGySU3J4wYE-wQXKeJypVS1PvjQhpCBmmOi0CPb4LAkxAA).</sub>

However, if the function or method has generic type parameters, [they get lost](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHYHMICULAK4CckAq4EAPAGIA0U6AfFALwCwAUFG1GVBAB7ARIATAM5QAFMDgBLIQC4o2JAGskAewDuSKgDodCXCllRJSAGYRcUAIIBKBnWQgoAfhbs3YnVr0G5Nu9SgZV3ZOHj5BEXEpQ2MzCwJtXX0Y03MrW3p7JEcXVnc2KOk5BKhPb0M-TICgvLYyAG4WFhMFAGNgSRUkKBMVFRICGlEEYqoAI2LrOQA3FUkBKABvAF8WUEgOPoYodYgVEx6+xuYAehPNlTkBoZGoEom7jLpZ+eO14igAIT1t+GQ0TA4fBESDkPpUBQCCAmYwQAQ0Y5nL56OTDOQKZTqTRQB4Y1QaJ7yQTQ2ECN7MVoAGwQQhEAGUVABbCAwam0lZNZjGPi4EwIVrQACSZC2i2CbGZEhUAgAjNc0XdxpMZnMyeKoJK4NKAEzyiRFKAM5msmlCKi3AhTKAvNW1DVYLUCADMeuioygtyQ2EZY3MVptx1WzHeGwAsg7pTLfohUBgsHhCMQSMK+gBtABEmsj6YAuhDiTCkHCESHoOGpQJtdH-nGgYnQSmVBms5Xc-moYXi8ddlBy46ndXY4CEyDSI3mxHnW2iR3SSXTuc+5HUbc8VilUTMQT-JCSUXbUil5XUfrDEaWWyzR70Up8UhCbvOwfF5OnSu5F6fX6dwXSfU2CQAC0gE7HA0CnlAYB6AgkppGgwAiJSKhCMAXBIB0uAQJSIBAA), and the corresponding function parameters become type `unknown`.

```js
type ChangeReturnType<F, R> =
    F extends (this: unknown, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (...args: A) => R :
    F extends (this: infer T, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (this: T, ...args: A) => R :
    F;

function foo<T>(a: T, b: T): void {}
type Foo = typeof foo;
// Foo: <T>(a: T, b: T) => void;

type Bar = ChangeReturnType<Foo, undefined>;
// Bar: (a: unknown, b: unknown) => undefined;

interface IFoo {
    method1<T>(a: T, b: T): void;
    method2<T>(this: SomeClass, a: T): void;
    method3<T>(this: T, a: number): void;
}

type Method1 = ChangeReturnType<IFoo["method1"], undefined>;
type Method2 = ChangeReturnType<IFoo["method2"], undefined>;
type Method3 = ChangeReturnType<IFoo["method3"], undefined>;
// Method1: (a: unknown, b: unknown) => undefined;
// Method2: (this: SomeClass, a: unknown) => undefined;
// Method3: (a: number) => undefined;  <-- the this parameter gets lost entirely
```

Of course, this is only type information, and it doesn't cause any issues at runtime, but the loss of the generics, and their implicit or explicit constraints, [can lead to uncaught errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHYHMICULAK4CckAq4EAPAGIA0U6AfFALwCwAUFG1GVBAB7ARIATAM5QAFMDgBLIQC4o2JAGskAewDuSKgDodCXCllRJSAGYRcUAIIBKBnWQgoAfhbs3YnVr0G5Nu9SgZV3ZOHj5BEXEpQ2MzCwJtXX0Y03MrW3p7JEcXVnc2KOk5BKhPb0M-TICgvLYyAG4WFhMFAGNgSRUkKBMVFRICGlEEYqoAI2LrOQA3FUkBKABvYLZJEzFQSBV1hAZ6eihNiG2oMesV91auoRUAGwgtW5UUUQADFUUEEDld5AWxqB6aBjFQSKAnI5QABEABJFkcTggAL5Q17WRq1Li3IQQC5uK5IG73LTmXAqXBvUnkn5GESw+HEREo8bYYCnWnQuEI9ZjFFojFIprMXoqUQARioYvRzT6oihCChVHlUOlzAA9GqerKJdCFei2CQALSGqAEADKACYAMwAFgArL59NgALb8NkQ4hQADkQmAuGMKC9HNUbIQQiEkhQSAQY3uhxUUDAegQrr4Fg9kG9SBdY3MXq0QoJvtOegYWoTYdgiFQGCweEIxBI3PLVAUAggJmMEAENAxYz04slqv7FOVSr1fYHOuV+o1UCNJoAcgmqRYTGTnaazSy2avAWzcApDpJXQBCIA).

```js
type ChangeReturnType<F, R> =
    F extends (this: unknown, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (...args: A) => R :
    F extends (this: infer T, ...args: infer A) => any ?
        (this: T, ...args: A) => R :
    F;

function foo<T>(a: T, b: T): void {
    if (typeof a === typeof b)
        console.log(`okay: a and b are both of type "${typeof a}"`);
    else
        console.error(`error: a is "${typeof a}", but b is "${typeof b}"`);
}

foo(1, 1);
foo("a", "a");
// foo(1, "a");  <-- TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

const bar = foo as ChangeReturnType<typeof foo, undefined>;
bar(1, 1);
bar("a", "a");
bar(1, "a"); // <-- No error from TS, but error at run time!
```

Is there any way to preserve generics in a conditional type like this?  It kind of seems like this is a job for [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but lacking that functionality, is there some sort of workaround that I can use to make this work, even in a limited scope?

Comment: The only workaround I know of is to use/abuse the [support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) by dropping from the type level to the value level, doing the transformation, and then pushing back up to the type level, as in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mbGZoW).  And even that is fragile and needs to sidestep conditional types.  If that meets your needs I can write it up as an answer; otherwise I don't think there is a way to do it.

Comment: @jcalz: Yes!  This seems like a very viable workaround, and is less kludgy than anything I had so far imagined.  I think it's pretty elegant in its simplicity, in fact.  The only problem I see is that it still loses the type of the `this` parameter in `IFoo.method3`.  Nonetheless, I think this will serve my purposes quite well.  Please do write it up as an answer, and please make note of whatever fragility you see in it.  I'm not sure I follow the problem you mentioned with conditional types.

Comment: Bonus points if you can make it work with something like [my "more meaningful" example](https://tsplay.dev/mpv6Xw) from above.

Comment: For the `IFoo.method3` the only solution I can come up with looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3aJ2w) but then all outputs have a `this` parameter, which is presumably why you're trying to use a conditional type in the first place.  The problem with conditional types is that you can't return `unknown extends T ? (...args:A)=>R : (this:T, ...args:A)=>R` without breaking the higher order type inference support; [the implementing PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) doesn't say this explicitly, but you can see how it only activates in very specific circumstances.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance although I don't know if I can spend much time mining for bonus points.

Comment: I can live without properly supporting `IFoo.method3`, but building something similar to the `Chain` type would be pretty useful.